# 'initialize' called before @FXML variables bound

Tags: scala, javafx, javafx-8

In my Scala application, I load the FXML file in the constructor of the controller and set the controller with `fxmlLoader.setController(this)`.

UPDATE (1): A more comprehensive example:

```
abstract class Controller[A <: Parent] {

  val root: A = loadRoot()
  private val stage: Stage = new Stage()

  def openWindow(): Unit = {
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root))
    stage.show()
    stage.toFront()
  }

  private def loadRoot(): A = {
    val loader = new FXMLLoader(getDefaultLocation())
    loader.setController(this)
    loader.load()
  }

  def getDefaultLocation(): URL = ???
}
```

--

```
class SampleController private() extends Controller[VBox] {
  @FXML private var text: TextField = _

  @FXML def initialize(): Unit =  {
    text.textProperty().set("That is some text.")
  }
}

object SampleController {
  def apply(): SampleController = new SampleController()
}
```

UPDATE (2): `SampleController()` is called whithin an Akka actor:

```
val controller = SampleController()
Platform.runLater(() => controller.openWindow())
```

I now experience that sometimes the *initialize* method is called before the c variables are bound. Can anyone think of any circumstances when that can happen?

Comment: not familiar with scala but .. this doesn't look like a [mcve], is it? If not, please provide it. Assuming that the basic mechanisms are similar to plain java, looks like you are self-loading the ui in the abstract parent's class field instantiation at which time descendant's fields are not yet known ..

Comment: @kleopatra I know that this might be no MRE. It is more like a sketch to ask if someone has seen something similar in similar circumstances. For me, the important part is: *I now experience that sometimes the initialize method is called before the c variables are bound. Can anyone think of any circumstances when that can happen?*

How can it be that sometimes it works, sometimes not? How can the loader the `initialize` method know but not the class variables?